# Json and html display

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I have a service I programmed to generate news. There is ATM close to 30 news types, each with different HTML code to display. For each case I get from the JSON returned by AJAX call the variable parts only, then generates the wanted HTML in JS and appends it to the container.

I found it very hard to work with, and a pain to debug. A lot of HTML generated in the JS looks to me like a bad thing. But I want the response from the server to be as light as it can, so I don't want to send back the whole HTML each time, it's so much better to send back only a little JSON.

Any idea of how I should do ?

Thanks ahead !

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Yea... use a JS templating engine like Mustache, the one in underscores.js, Handlebars (note: I know about these things, but haven't really used). A lot of HTML generated by JS is NOT a bad thing inherently... it *can* be a very good thing if done right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a good template engine like http://handlebarsjs.com/. They also have debug handlers

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need... I already used Smarty in the past, with PHP, so it won't be hard to learn and use something like handlebars. Is it the best around here ?

Comment: which one is the best is hard to say but i would say that it is one of the good ones :) Maybe this helps you a bit http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Comment: Okay, I read a lot now about comparing these tools, looks like Dust.js is actually the best, but Handlebars is very good too. Here is one more question : would I be able to do what I exposed in my first post using Angularjs or such ?

Comment: angularJs is more than just a layout engine. it's a framework for developing whole apps, you could compare it to php symfony or ruby on rails etc. but on the client side. Definitly worth to try it out though. Maybe you want to look at ember.js too. (also such a framework)

Comment: Yes, I know what it is, read a lot about it, but since I never used it, I was wondering if it gives the opportunity to do so or, assuming I use it on a project, I should add Dust or Handlebars also. I read some topics about that but the question is about the current concern, which is being able to template html within the javascript.

Comment: if u just want templates than do not use the whole angularjs/ember.js etc. frameworks. You might be able to just use their templating system, which is in case of ember.js is handlebars. So to answer your question: no do not use angular.js for templating only.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to use Angular Directives. That will make the html well organized and easy to read( if you are modeling the JSON at Client Side).

Angular got may features which will help in your case ( Typically News, Blogs sites).

Comment: Yes but using Angular just for this is a little "overkill", I think... Besides, I don't think I would be able to get it work with the project I work on now, old project with a lot of wierd things...